# batch execute iPython Notebook with command line argument?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm using `nbconvert` to execute an iPython notebook via the command line (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17913858/718139)):

`ipython nbconvert --to=html --ExecutePreprocessor.enabled=True RunMe.ipynb`

Is it possible to pass command line arguments to be accessed from within the notebook (like `sys.argv`)?

This would let me reuse the same notebook in different contexts.

Answer (score 11):

You can access environmental variables instead. I have yet to come across a way to use command line arguments directly.

Comment: A bit awkward, but yeah, that'd be the way to go if it's not possible.

Comment: Have you found a way that's possible? Because I'm loving how folks down voting this without giving a better answer.

Comment: Have not found anything better! I didn't down-vote, but my guess is no one would down-vote if you hadn't framed the answer as if there's no need for the functionality I'm asking for. (environment variables work but it's awkward!)

Comment: Along those lines, you may use one environment variable: `NB_ARGS='--par1 val1 --par2 val2' jupyter nbconvert mynotebook.html --execute --stdout > myoutput.html` and use `argparse, os` inside the notebook, as `parser.parse_args(os.environ['NB_ARGS'])`. At least there is only one variable involved...

Answer (score 2):

[This is my attempt at a single module](https://gist.github.com/gbishop/acf40b86a9bca2d571fa) for argument parsing in Python scripts and Jupyter notebooks. It only supports minimalist key=value style arguments but meets my needs.

I nbconvert it to a Python script named Args.py and use it as shown.

Then I can batch run a notebook like:

`jpn mynotebook limit=5 assignment=A2`