# Running a Julia script in a remote Jupyter Notebook, with arguments

Tags: json, jupyter-notebook, julia, remote-server, ijulia-notebook

I am running a Julia script in a Jupyter Notebook on a remote host by using the following command in a jupyter-environment

```
jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute my_notebook.ipynb
```

which works fine. However, if I try to pass arguments to the Jupyter Notebook with the intention to be finally passed to the Julia script I fail. My question is how to do it?

- To pass arguments to the Jupyter Notebook I modified the above command to

```
jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute my_notebook.ipynb arg1 arg2 arg3
```

- Also, in the Julia script I try to recover the arguments (which are supposed to be small enough integers) via

```
x1 = parse(Int16, ARGS[1])
x2 = parse(Int16, ARGS[2])
x3 = parse(Int16, ARGS[3])
```

which doesn't work.

- I tried to understand what is in ARGS, but I can't decipher what it means. The output of

```
println(ARGS)
```

included in the Julia script is

```
"/tmp/tmp8vuj5f79.json"
```

Coming back to the second bullet point, a few errors occur since ARGS[1] obviously can't be converted to an integer.

- Another error which occurs when passing the arguments to the Jupyter Notebook execution is

```
[NbConvertApp] WARNING | pattern 'arg1' matched no files
[NbConvertApp] WARNING | pattern 'arg2' matched no files
[NbConvertApp] WARNING | pattern 'arg3' matched no files
```

I might be approaching the problem from a completely wrong perspective, so any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It [looks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080715/batch-execute-ipython-notebook-with-command-line-argument) [like](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/681) it's not possible to pass in command-line arguments to `--execute`d notebooks.
The `WARNING | pattern 'arg1' matched no files` messages indicate that these arguments are seen by nbconvert as additional files to convert, not as arguments to the notebook.

The common suggestion is to use environment variables instead.

```
X=12 Y=5 Z=42 jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute my_notebook.ipynb
```

which you can then access from within the notebook as
`ENV["X"]`, `ENV["Y"]`, and `ENV["Z"]`.