# Can I run Jupyter notebook cells in commandline?

Tags: python, command-line, ipython, jupyter

I am deploying a Python package, and I would like to run a simple test to see if all cells in my notebook will run without errors.  I would like to test this via commandline as I have issues running a notebook in `virtualenv`.  Is there are simple command-line way to test this?

---

Note to the moderator:  this question has been marked as a duplicate of [How to run an .ipynb Jupyter Notebook from terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545402/how-to-run-an-ipynb-jupyter-notebook-from-terminal)
.  However, this question was posted (asked Feb 18 '16 at 2:49) several days before that one (asked Feb 22 '16 at 3:35). At most, that post might be marked as a duplicate, and if deemed so, an appropriate action would be to [merge the two questions, maintaining this, the original, as the master](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309004/4531270).

However, these questions *may not* be duplicates (the intent of the other author is unclear).  Regardless, this question and it's answers specifically address **executing cells within a jupyter notebook from the terminal**, not simply converting notebooks to python files.

Comment: Related discussion: [Run Jupyter Notebook (.ipynb) from command line as if it were a .py file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43602938/320399)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run an .ipynb Jupyter Notebook from terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545402/how-to-run-an-ipynb-jupyter-notebook-from-terminal)

Comment: If using pytest, [`nbsmoke`](https://github.com/pyviz/nbsmoke) is a plugin that claims to accomplish this.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use [runipy](https://github.com/paulgb/runipy) to do this.

`runipy` will run all cells in a notebook.  If an error occurs, the process will stop.

> `$ pip install runipy`
>
> `$ runipy MyNotebook.ipynb`

There are also commands for saving the output file as a notebook or an html report:

> `$ runipy MyNotebook.ipynb OutputNotebook.ipynb`
>
> `$ runipy MyNotebook.ipynb --html report.html`

Comment: This answer is correct, but was superseded in the latest versions of jupyter by the ``nbconvert`` command

Comment: or `papermill` as suggested below as well.

Answer (score 132):

`nbconvert` (a jupyter tool for notebook conversion) allows you to do this without any extra packages:

Just go to your terminal and type

> $ jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --inplace --execute mynotebook.ipynb

[Source](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#convert-notebook)

(Thanks Stephan for suggesting the `--inplace` flag)

**NOTE**: This said, I'd try to convert everything you need to a proper script. Jupyter notebooks are thought for exploring and sharing results, and not as a replacement of traditional programs.

Comment: I like the idea of using nbconvert more than a separate package, although when I tried this I ran into [this issue](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda_kernels/issues/34)

Comment: You can use the --inplace flag as well:
`jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute --inplace mynotebook.ipynb`

Comment: Nbconvert will fail if any cell takes longer than 30s to run, you may want to add `--ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=600`.

Comment: Documentation or this and programmatic ways of running notebooks can be found at https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html#module-nbconvert.preprocessors

Comment: @bckygldstn Any way to drop the timeout all together? Or would I just need to set a really high value?

Comment: @CGFoX The timeout can be removed by setting to `None` or `-1` as per https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html#execution-arguments-traitlets

Comment: Another helpful flag is `--ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name=julia-1.6`, or whatever kernel you need.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  I have `print()` statements in my notebook and none of these are output when "executing" the notebook. If I "Download As" > ".py" and run that via python, then I see the print statements as expected. So..how to do the same thing from the command line?

Comment: @sh37211 I suggest you create a script from your notebook. This method is not flawless, and if you expect to have some output then a notebook is not a good fit for you

Answer (score 18):

You can also try [papermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill)  which allows you to execute notebooks from command line, and also pass parameters:

For example:

```
$ papermill mynotebook.ipynb mynotebook_output.ipynb -p start "2017-11-01" -p end "2017-11-30"
```

You can also run it without passing any parameter.

Comment: papermill has a nice console ui with execution status and times, so I actually recommend using it instead of `nbconvert` if you want some executing monitoring

Comment: Does not execute in the usual sense.   Print statements in the notebook do not go to stdout during execution, like converting to .py & running would do.  Instead what you get is a whole new notebook file.  ??

Answer (score 0):

You could use `nbconvert` to convert the `ipynb` file into a python script and then run it.

`jupyter nbconvert --to python notebook.ipynb`

`python3 notebook.py`

Comment: [Jupytext](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) also converts notebooks to scripts and has some other abilities that make it a nice tool to have in your toolbox. It can execute notebooks from the command line directly as well.