# How to run an .ipynb Jupyter Notebook from terminal?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, nbconvert

I have some code in a .ipynb file and got it to the point where I don't really need the "interactive" feature of IPython Notebook. I would like to just run it straight from a Mac Terminal Command Line.

Basically, if this were just a .py file, I believe I could just do `python filename.py` from the command line. Is there something similar for a .ipynb file?

Comment: Something like this: https://github.com/paulgb/runipy ?

Comment: if you go to the runipy page referenced above you see that it is unmaintained and they point to Jupyter's "execute api" at https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html

Answer (score 171, accepted):

From the command line you can convert a notebook to python with this command:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to python nb.ipynb
```

https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert

You may have to install the python [mistune](https://pypi.org/project/mistune) package:

```
sudo pip install -U mistune
```

Comment: Subcommand `ipython nbconvert` is deprecated in favor of jupyter nbconvert

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. II realise it works but the question is how to run .ipynb from terminal, not how to convert it into a .py and then run it.

Comment: Nbconvert will fail if any cell takes longer than 30s to run, you may want to add `--ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=600`.

Comment: The latest updates makes it work like this, you get a HTML out the notebook file `jupyter-nbconvert --execute 03-Print\ Formatting\ with\ Strings.ipynb`

Answer (score 240):

nbconvert allows you to run notebooks with the `--execute` flag:

```
jupyter nbconvert --execute <notebook>
```

If you want to run a notebook and produce a new notebook, you can add `--to notebook`:

```
jupyter nbconvert --execute --to notebook <notebook>
```

Or if you want to *replace* the existing notebook with the new output:

```
jupyter nbconvert --execute --to notebook --inplace <notebook>
```

Since that's a really long command, you can use an alias:

```
alias nbx="jupyter nbconvert --execute --to notebook"
nbx [--inplace] <notebook>
```

Comment: This turns the notebook into a static HTML page

Comment: Documentation or this and programmatic ways of running notebooks can be found at https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html#module-nbconvert.preprocessors

Comment: Is there a way to specify which cells to execute? For example cell 10 and all below, or a range cell 10 to cell 20.

Comment: Also, if you have long running cells, [you can set](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html) `--ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=[timeout_in_seconds]` (use `-1` for no restriction).

Comment: The latest updates makes it work like this, you get a HTML out the notebook file `jupyter-nbconvert --execute 03-Print\ Formatting\ with\ Strings.ipynb`

Comment: For me the first command produces an error `Please specify an output format with '--to <format>'.`. It works with `jupyter nbconvert --to python --execute <notebook>`.

Comment: I had to do the following steps to get nbconvert to run
 `pip install ipykernel ` and
`python -m ipykernel install --user --name=python3`

Comment: This didn't return a non-zero exit code with an error code when a cell within the notebook encountered an execution error

Answer (score 63):

In your Terminal run ipython:

```
ipython
```

then locate your script and put there:

```
%run your_script.ipynb
```

Comment: how could this be put into a shell script

Comment: @baxx `ipython -c "%run your_script.ipynb"`

Comment: can you do a Makefile with this?

Comment: @CarlosMougan see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68720825/2641825) using [nbconvert](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html#example) to run notebooks from python.

Answer (score 43):

You can export all your code from `.ipynb` and save it as a `.py` script. Then you can run the script in your terminal.

[image: code export sample]

Hope it helps.

Comment: doesn't answer the original question

Answer (score 28):

Using **ipython**:

```sh
ipython --TerminalIPythonApp.file_to_run=<notebook>.ipynb
```

Normally, I would prefer this option as it is really self-describing. If you prefer to use less characters, use:

```sh
ipython -c "%run <notebook>.ipynb"
```

which is basically what [Keto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7898913/keto) already suggested (unfortunately a little bit hidden) as a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545402/how-to-run-an-ipynb-jupyter-notebook-from-terminal#comment113515332_58774096).

Comment: Guys, admit it, you would not find the comment without this answer, so why not upvote both?:)

Comment: I'd also like to add that it is prudent to specify an absolute path to the notebook (it can save you a lot of searching if `ipython` is not the only part of the "run chain" (in my case `ipython` was inside a bash script run from a Kubernetes CronJob and it would fail without the full absolute path to the notebook).

Answer (score 12):

In my case, the command that best suited me was:

```
jupyter nbconvert --execute --clear-output <notebook>.ipynb
```

Why? This command does not create extra files (just like a `.py` file) and the output of the cells is overwritten everytime the notebook is executed.

If you run:

```
jupyter nbconvert --help
```

> --clear-output
>   Clear output of current file and save in place, overwriting the existing notebook.

Answer (score 10):

For new version instead of:

```
ipython nbconvert --to python <YourNotebook>.ipynb
```

You can use jupyter instend of ipython:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to python <YourNotebook>.ipynb
```

Comment: how is this an answer to the question?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and I found [papermill](https://papermill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). The advantages against the others solutions is that you can see the results while the notebook is running. I find this feature interesting when the notebook takes very long. It is very easy to use:

```
pip install papermill
papermill notebook.ipynb output.ipynb
```

It has also, other handy options as saving the output file to Amazon S3, Google Cloud, etc. See the page for more information.

Comment: papermill also 1) displays a progress bar of your notebooks execution, 2) save the notebook executed without touching the original notebook, 3) In case of execution failure, the executed notebook will show you exactly where (the cell number is provided and the cell is highlighted in red) you code failed. It also has many configuration feature. papermill is likely better than `nbconvert` and quite easy to use.

Answer (score 6):

There is now a `jupyter execute` subcommand that will execute a notebook.

```
jupyter execute notebook.ipynb
```

More on this command can be found in the [Jupyter documentation](https://docs.jupyter.org/en/latest/running.html#using-a-command-line-interface).

Answer (score 5):

**Update with quoted comment by author for better visibility:**

> Author's note "This project started before Jupyter's execute API, which is now the recommended way to run notebooks from the command-line. Consider runipy deprecated and unmaintained." – Sebastian Palma

Install runipy library that allows running your code on terminal

```
pip install runipy
```

After just compiler your code:

```
runipy <YourNotebookName>.ipynb
```

You can try cronjob as well. All information is [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/runipy)

Comment: Author's note "This project started before Jupyter's execute API, which is now the recommended way to run notebooks from the command-line.

Consider runipy deprecated and unmaintained."

Answer (score 5):

I've made some research on this topic and wrote an article on [4 ways to run Jupyter Notebook in command line](https://mljar.com/blog/run-jupyter-notebook-command-line/) below is summary of my findings.

### 1. Use `nbconvert`

The [nbconvert](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert) package is already installed in Jupyter Notebook. It can be used to execute notebook. Additionally it has many features:

- can export notebook to PDF or HTML,
- can hide code in output notebook,
- can execute notebook even with errors in cells.

Example notebook execution:

```bash
jupyter nbconvert --execute --to notebook --allow-errors your-notebook.ipynb
```

The above command will output `your-notebook.nbconvert.ipynb` file and will execute all cells even with errors.

### 2. Use `papermill`

The [papermill](https://papermill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) allows you to parametrize notebook. You can define variables as parameters (with cell tags).

Example command:

```bash
papermill -p name Piotrek your-notebook.ipynb output-notebook.ipynb
```

Example notebook with injected parameters:
[image: notebook with injected parameters by papermill]

### 3. Manually download notebook as `.py` script

There is an option to manually download notebook as `.py` script:

[image: download notebook as Python script]

After download you can add execution rights to the file and run it as a command line script.

### 4. Use `jupytext`

The [jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext) package allows you to synchronize `.ipynb` file with `.py` file. You don't need to manually convert notebook to script.

Comment: Unfortunately, pairing .ipynb with .py in jupytext does not seem to work. Would be great if it did.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `boar` package to run your notebook within a python code.

```py
from boar.running import run_notebook

outputs = run_notebook("nb.ipynb")
```

If you update your notebook, you won't have to convert it again to a python file.

---

More information at:

https://github.com/alexandreCameron/boar/blob/master/USAGE.md

Answer (score 2):

From the terminal run

```
jupyter nbconvert --execute --to notebook --inplace --allow-errors --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=-1 my_nb.ipynb
```

The default timeout is 30 seconds. -1 removes the restriction.

If you wish to save the output notebook to a new notebook you can use the flag `--output my_new_nb.ipynb`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `jupytext` https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html.

This allows you to pair your notebook. So for each `ipynb` file you have a `.py` file as well with some comments. The `.py` file can be executed as usual.
You can enjoy benefits of two worlds with the cost of one extra file though.

Oh, and by the way if you are using version control you can only commit `.py` files with a nice diff instead of the ugly `.ipynb` diffs.

(The syntax in the `.py` files is similar to Databricks notebooks iy you are familiar with them...)

Answer (score -1):

In a batch file paste the below. Use ipython to run .ipynb files.

```
@echo on
call "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat"
ipython "path\test.ipynb"
pause
```