# Name Error: name 'get_ipython' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors, ipython

I'm trying to run the following few lines with ipython (3.5 version):

```
import sys
from init_mooc_nb import *
init_notebook()
```

I would like some help to figure out what is the error (see below).

Thank you in advance.

[Complete Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2h5jF.png)

Comment: try running this via `ipython`, i.e: `ipython script_name.py` and see if the error exists.

Comment: What did you name your file?

Comment: Thank you Jim and user2357112.    
In the description above, I did exactly as Jim said. I put the code lines in a file named _test.py_ and run with `ipython test.py`.

I realised that those lines work in a Jupyter notebook.
Then I have created a notebook file _test.ipynb_ and run through Jupyter environment (browser front-end). Now it is working good :)

I still don't know how to run this file _test.ipynb_ from terminal. Is that possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545402/running-ipynb-from-terminal

Comment: Thank you, iparjono

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that this is part of an ipython notebook and needs to be run in ipython notebook... (use e.g.  `jupyter notebook`or `ipython -notebook` from command line to start it...)

Comment: Exactly. Tks ntg

Comment: Thnx. Note:  they renamed ipython notebook to jupyter, so use `jupyter notebook` instead (updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Intellij Idea with the Python plugin:
Put your notebooks inside a python package and then right click the package and select `Mark directory as -> Load Path Root`

There's an open bug on the Intellij idea team [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DS-2860)

Comment: Thanks Royal, the issue was solved with the previous comments. But this might be useful to someone else. Thanks for sharing.