# Global Script to Run Another Python (ipynb) Script if Condition is Met

Tags: python, if-statement, call, global

I have the following user input Code:

```
# User Run Code Below to: input start day of week 

start_of_week = input ("input value: ")

print ("----------------------------------------------------- ")
print("Your weekly aggregated weather data will start on:" + " " + start_of_week)
```

Then I enter Monday in the input box and press enter.  As a result my start_of_week variable is successfully set to Monday.

I want to run the following code to call and execute another Python script in my jupyter notebook:

```
import subprocess
if start_of_week == 'Monday':
    subprocess.call(['python', 'fnDerVar_Discrete_Rain&Snow_RangeBucket_12.8.ipynb'])
else:
    subprocess.call(['python', 'fnWSICleanHistPull_HrtoWeek_10.17_Edited_weekenddate_Arch.ipynb'])
```

However, when I run it...nothing happens.  If the code had run my first script successfully (which met my user input condition of Monday), then I should get an output CSV file.  However, I don't get one.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think there is an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545402/running-ipynb-from-terminal)

Comment: this is not quite what I'm looking for.  I want to run another ipynb script from an existing ipynb script.