# unable to execute .ipynb files from terminal

Tags: terminal, jupyter, nbconvert

referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545402/running-ipynb-from-terminal/35545463) question

@minrk in his answer mentioned that

```
jupyter nbconvert --execute --to notebook --inplace <notebook>
```

would replace the existing notebook with the new output:
But when I tried executing the above command in the terminal I am getting an error. I have attached the relevant photos below.

Thanks in advance

ERROR:

[image: Error while running the command in terminal]

This is my .ipynb file:
[image]