# how to run graphlab that is ipynb file directly without opening the source code?

Tags: graphlab

I have created a ipynb file using graphlab to analyse some data in a csv. But every time I need to run it, I have to open the source code in Jupyter. I want to know how to run and execute the ipynb file without opening the script every time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running .ipynb from terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545402/running-ipynb-from-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, thanks for asking this question as your question has actually been recognized by many programmers and researchers who use `Jupyter` and one of my friend wrote a thesis as well as research paper on this problem, exploring ways to automate so that you don't need to run each cell every-time.

For your question, I personally do prefer to accommodate all lines of code in one cell of `Jupyter` and run it only once so that I don't need to repeat again & again. Multiple lines of code in one cell can run together like a separate `.py` file and you don't need to repeat the process. I hope this can help you as well.