# Google CoLab - How to run a jupyter notebook file that is in the 'Files' tab (i.e. /content/) of my CoLab environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory

In Google CoLab on the left is a pane that can be opened that shows `Table of Contents`, `Code snippets`, and `Files`.
In the `Files` pane there is an upload button, I can upload a notebook file to this `Files` area. But once the notebook file is uploaded, there is no option to run it as a notebook. The menu option `File->OpenNotebook` doesn't show the CoLab `/content/` files as an option to start a notebook.
Is there a way to do this? Or can it be added in future releases?

The reason for this request is I'd like to git-clone a repo with multiple notebook files into the `/content` (or `Files`) area of CoLab. And then be able to easily switch between the notebooks, much like the native Jupyter notebook interface that shows a directory with potentially multiple notebooks that can be started.

I've tried right-clicking on the notebook file in `Files` but there is no option to start the notebook. I've tried using `File->Open_notebook`... the `Files` files aren't shown as an option in any of the tabs.

The desired results is that I can start .ipynb files (i.e. Jupyter notebooks) directly from the 'Files' or `/content/` section of Google CoLab.

Answer (score 5):

You can run other notebooks in your current notebook like this:

```
# if the file was on the google drive
%run /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebooks/DenseVideoArchitecture.ipynb

# simply replace the path in your case
%run /content/DenseVideoArchitecture.ipynb
```

But what you are asking is to switch between different notebooks in the same environment which might not be possible in collab.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't understand what you actually need, but I hope below code help you:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')

!cd content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks
```

You should mount your google drive and now you have access to drive as a local drive. In this code, at first two lines, I mount gdrive and then  I redirect to some place in google drive for example "Colab Notebooks" and you can run everything you want.

Comment: No, this is not what I mean. I'm not trying to open a notebook from my google drive, I'm trying to open a notebook within the CoLab filesystem itself, one that I have placed in the CoLab filesystem by git-cloning it there.

Comment: I think you should convert that file and then run it. maybe this link helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545402/how-to-run-an-ipynb-jupyter-notebook-from-terminal .  Also, you can clone it to gdrive and use it because the files in colab file are temporary and after restart runtime, they will be cleared.