# Can I open ipynb files from local runtime as notebooks without uploading them to my Google Drive?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, localhost, google-colaboratory

I have connected to a local runtime of a Jupyter Notebook in Google Colab.

As you can see in [my Collaborator tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pR7Jy.png) I have a file called "**My_Agent.ipynb**" that I opened from my Google Drive (middle) and another, different, "My_Agent.ipynb" file (right) that I opened by double clicking that file name on the left.

Normally I would want to be able to open and edit all the .ipynb files on the left by doubling clicking them. Instead I get the format on the right which is not a notebook (it doesn't have cells) and as you can see it says I can't edit it.

The google drive file and the file on my local runtime are different files. Is it possible to open and edit the one in my local runtime without uploading it to my Google Drive?

It is the same unanswered question as this: [Google CoLab - How to run a jupyter notebook file that is in the 'Files' tab (i.e. /content/) of my CoLab environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55814631/google-colab-how-to-run-a-jupyter-notebook-file-that-is-in-the-files-tab-i?newreg=1fe615f99ac545f0a19215593bcceff7)
, but hopefully more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's protection against our stupidity.
I'm sure at some point you and I would lose a lot of work when the runtime closes or resets.