# How to schedule a datalab ipynb to run regularly

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, schedule

I want to schedule for my codes in a datalab (from Google Cloud Platform, or GCP) ipynb file to run regularly (say, 1 per day). Please help to shed some light on possible workarounds. Thanks!

- I think GCP cloud scheduler or cron jobs (cron.ysml) should do it, but I'm not sure how they work exactly.

Here are the codes in my ipynb (which works okay):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import io

url = "https://www.taiwanlottery.com.tw/lotto/superlotto638/history.aspx"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read(),
                     features="html.parser", from_encoding='utf-8')

css_url = "https://www.taiwanlottery.com.tw/css1.css"

soup_css = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(
    css_url).read(), features="html.parser", from_encoding='utf-8')


table = soup.find("table", id="SuperLotto638Control_history1_dlQuery")

with io.open("superLottery.html", "w", encoding='utf-16') as f:
    f.write(unicode(table))
    f.write(unicode('<style type = "text/css">'))
    f.write(unicode(soup_css))
    f.write(unicode("</style>"))

!gsutil cp 'superLottery.html' 'gs://astral-petal-222508.appspot.com/datalab-backups/asia-east1-a/new-env'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that scheduling a periodic run of an `ipython` `notebook` from *Cloud Datalab* could be too much of an anti pattern to be encouraged.

The *jupyter* "server" is running inside a container on a *Compute Engine VM instance*.

At first thought, one could hope to achieve this to convert a "notebook" to a regular *Python* module and then run it remotely, the problem is the third party libraries dependencies that you might have in place.

Even if there are no dependencies, the [required software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545402/how-to-run-an-ipynb-jupyter-notebook-from-terminal) to convert the  `notebook` isn't installed on the `container`'s image so you'd need to install it on every run between instance restarts.

You could also convert it "yourself", and while this is not guaranteed to run successfully in every case, as a deeper research on how `notebook`s format is (even though a first glance doesn't seem too complicated), I'll demonstrate how to do it below.

So, let's pipe the `notebook` source code to the `exec` [Built-in Function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec), load our dependencies so our `exec` call runs successfully.

All of this remotely, through the *datalab* `container` running on the *VM instance*.

```
$ project= #TODO edit
$ zone= #TODO edit
$ instance= #TODO edit

$ gcloud compute ssh $instance --project $project --zone $zone -- docker exec datalab python '-c """
import json
import imp

#TODO find a better way and not escape quote characters?...

bs4 = imp.load_package(\"bs4\", \"/usr/local/envs/py2env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4\")
BeautifulSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup

notebook=\"/content/datalab/notebooks/notebook0.ipynb\"

source_exclude = (\"from bs4 import BeautifulSoup\")

with open(notebook) as fp:
    source = \"\n\".join(line for cell in json.load(fp)[\"cells\"] if cell[\"cell_type\"]==\"code\" for line in cell[\"source\"] if line not in source_exclude)


#print(source)

exec(source)
"""
'
```

So far, I couldn't couldn't find another way to not escape the characters as my `bash`'s expertise is not much.

You'll also, at least, get warnings related with some of the `imp.load_package` libraries's dependencies not being available. This remind us how this approach is not scalable at all.

I don't know what do you think of this but perhaps is better to have the *Python* source code you want to run on a *Cloud Function* and then trigger that function with *Cloud Scheduler*. Check out this [community example](https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-functions-tutorial-using-the-cloud-scheduler-to-trigger-your-functions-756160a95c43) for that.

I believe a reasonable take from this post is that a `notebook` can have different use cases than a *Python* `module`.

Also, make sure to go through the *Cloud Datalab* [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to) to at least understand some of the concepts this answer relates with.