# Invoke several Jupyter Notebook sequentially

Tags: jupyter-notebook, invoke

Our team has developed python script to process data in 10 separated but functionally related jupyter notebooks, i.e. output of notebook 1 will be used as input for notebook 2 and so on.

Our next step is to automate the data processing process. Are there any ways to sequentially invoke jupyter notebooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nbconvert` allows you to run notebooks. To run a notebook and replace the existing output with the new one, you can use.

```
jupyter nbconvert --execute --to notebook --inplace <notebook>
```

For more options and different approaches, you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545402/how-to-run-an-ipynb-jupyter-notebook-from-terminal)
You can create a script with the above commands for each notebook and this should be able to execute the notebooks in the sequential order.

```yaml
Script:
jupyter nbconvert --execute --to notebook --inplace <notebook1>
jupyter nbconvert --execute --to notebook --inplace <notebook2>

Run script.
```

Comment: I tried this, but I am getting the error: DeadlockkernelError(kernel Died) @skillsmuggler

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way would be to arrange file names in alphabetical order,
and then in the terminal, you can use

```
jupyter nbconvert --inplace --execute *.ipynb
```

Note that, `--inplace` overwrites the notebook in itself (same file) after execution.