# Connecting local Jupiter Notebook to Remote Putty Session

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, putty

I have a Python script on my local Jupiter notebook. Right now, I run a command on a Putty session to generate some data that I write to an output text file and the download to my local to be able to be read into the Python script. Is there any way to be able to write a command and do this from the script itself?

Comment: isn't this what you want ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545402/how-to-run-an-ipynb-jupyter-notebook-from-terminal

Comment: Not exactly. In the script I want to be able to run a command in a remote server.

Answer (score 2):

You can run the commands over ssh from python via `paramiko` library : https://www.paramiko.org

Example from the official documentation:

```
client = SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect('ssh.example.com')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls -l')
```