# Running python script in cmd does not give any output

Tags: python

This is my python path in environment variable

```
C:\Users\Kiwi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\
C:\Users\Kiwi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\
```

If I run `C:\Users\Kiwi>python --version` in cmd it resulted `Python 3.7.4`

This is the script I want to run in cmd, the location of the script is
`C:\Users\Kiwi\JUPYTER_FILES\test_script.ipynb`

```
import numpy as np
array = np.arange(0,10)
print(array)
print('hello');
```

I'm trying to run that python script from cmd but it does not give any ouput when I run it.

```
C:\Users\Kiwi>python C:\Users\Kiwi\JUPYTER_FILES\test_script.ipynb

C:\Users\Kiwi> //it just went blank like this after above command
```

I don't know what's wrong. After I did lots of reading and other questions, nothing works. I already set the environment variable right, I could execute that python version command, I already run the python script with it's full path but it still does not return anything while the script is very simple and literally print 2 things. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: `.ipynb` suggests that the script is actually a Jupyter notebook. Running it with Python is probably interpreting the file structure as a dictionary, meaning there should not be an output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run an .ipynb Jupyter Notebook from terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545402/how-to-run-an-ipynb-jupyter-notebook-from-terminal)