# Can I run .NET Interactive (.ipynb) from Command Line?

Tags: .net, powershell

I have a .NET Interactive Notebook, works fine when I execute from VS Code with the [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.dotnet-interactive-vscode)

This contains a sequence of `PowerShell` scripts, that I use for local builds on my system

I want to re-use the same in CI

Is there a way to `Invoke` the `ipynb` file from command line?

---

**Edit**

I did come across [PowerShellNotebook](https://github.com/dfinke/PowerShellNotebook) module

So I can do something like

```
Invoke-ExecuteNotebook -InputNotebook .\quick.ipynb
```

*Problem is*

I refer to files using relative path (reading json, importing module, ...) the relative path doesn't work very well with `Invoke-ExecuteNotebook`

Meaning, something like this won't work
https://i.imgur.com/E9h0EbF.png
https://i.imgur.com/Jv2zxKr.png

I tries `Get-Location`, `Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent`

Both didn't work for finding current location

Comment: What do you mean by "_I refer to files using relative path (reading json, importing module, ...) the relative path doesn't work very well with Invoke-ExecuteNotebook_"?

Comment: If I try to do something like

```ps1
$currentPath = Get-Location
Remove-Item (Resolve-Path "$currentPath\hello.txt")
```

It errors out

Comment: But what's the error? What does it say? EDIT: Ok, I see you've edited a question. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is support for running .NET Interactive notebooks (including both the .ipynb and .dib formats) in [dotnet-repl](https://github.com/jonsequitur/dotnet-repl#-run-a-notebook-script-or-code-file-and-then-exit). Unlike with Papermill, it's not necessary to install a Jupyter kernel when using dotnet-repl.

```
dotnet repl --run /path/to/input.ipynb --output-path /path/to/output.ipynb --exit-after-run --output-format ipynb
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing (April 2023) this doesn't seem possible out of the box.
There's an open issue for this on the .NET Interactive GitHub repo.
https://github.com/dotnet/interactive/issues/839

The [PowerShellNotebook](https://github.com/dfinke/PowerShellNotebook) module you mentioned in the edit is an option you can use. From [this blogpost](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/announcing-net-interactive-try-net-includes-net-notebooks-and-more) and [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62933760/13090245) I discovered there's also [Papermill](https://papermill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage-execute.html) from nteract, which can execute your notebooks provided they are using the `.ipynb` file format.

In my case I got this to work by first installing .NET Interactive CLI and the Jupyter kernels with.

`dotnet tool install --global Microsoft.dotnet-interactive`

`dotnet-interactive jupyter install`

`python3 -m pip install papermill`

`papermill --kernel .net-powershell notebook.ipynb output.ipynb`

One limitation of this that I've found is that `papermill` can only handle one kernel at a time -- that is to say, you can't mix C# and Powershell in a notebook.

Comment: Combining languages in one notebook should work, since the kernel itself is polyglot-aware.

Comment: This seems to be a limitation of papermill, not the kernel. https://github.com/nteract/papermill/blob/main/papermill/execute.py Either way, your solution is cleaner.