# How to execute a * .IPYNB file from a * .PY file?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I wrote some scripts in .ipynb, now I want to schedule automatically using windows tool to run all scripts.
I thought of scheduling just one .py file to run all the scripts.
**Which command do I use to run .ipynb inside a .py file?**
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was already answered but in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67811531/how-can-i-execute-a-ipynb-notebook-file-in-a-python-script#:%7E:text=ipynb%20notebooks%20are%20actually%20just,the%20code%20using%20exec()%20.) question. The user [amicitas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260839/amicitas) said:

*You can use the nbconvert package to execute ipython/jupyter notebooks from within python. Instructions are available within the nbconvert documentation: Executing notebooks.*

*Here is a short example*

```
import nbformat
from nbconvert.preprocessors import ExecutePreprocessor

filename = 'NotebookName.ipynb'
with open(filename) as ff:
    nb_in = nbformat.read(ff, nbformat.NO_CONVERT)
    
ep = ExecutePreprocessor(timeout=600, kernel_name='python3')

nb_out = ep.preprocess(nb_in)
```

*The output is an ipython/jupyter notebook including the output of all cells.*

Comment: If a question is a duplicate you should flag it as a duplicate instead of copying the answer