# Is it possible to execute multiple code blocks in a manner similar to 'restart and run all' automatically on colab/jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have a neural network that's being trained for regression tasks. I want to run certain combinations of features as my input X to assess the prediction performance for y. As of now all I can do is manually make a bunch of functions and execute the feature list in a loop.

I was wondering if I could write code within another code block whose job is to iterate through this 'feature list' and re-execute the notebook and at each time?

Any advice on this? Thank you!

Comment: It's called defining a function.

Comment: Yes, I have functions defined for importing data, training, tuning and testing. What I meant was more along the lines of 'can you code in "restart and run all" into a code block instead of putting everything in loops or manually hitting that option on colab/jupyter?'

Comment: Now put all of that into another function with arguments being your features, and call it in a loop with different features.

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, you can refactor your code into functions. However, please find below a general approach:

1. **Refactor code into functions**: break down your code into functions that can be easily called with different sets of features. For example, you might have a function for preprocessing, one for training the model, and one for evaluating the model.
2. **Feature combinations**: create a list or generator of feature combinations that you want to iterate over.
3. **Iteration**: loop over the feature combinations, calling the functions you have defined with each set.

For example:

```
import itertools

def preprocess_data(features, data):
    return preprocessed_data

def train_model(X, y):
    return model

def evaluate_model(model, X, y):
    return error

all_features = ['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3', ...]

for i in range(1, len(all_features)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(all_features, i):
        X = preprocess_data(subset, dfclean)

        model = train_model(X, dfclean['y'])

        error = evaluate_model(model, X, dfclean['y'])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the contribution! I have functions defined for importing data, training, tuning and testing. What I meant was more along the lines of 'can you code in "restart and run all" into a code block instead of putting everything in loops or manually hitting that option on colab/jupyter?' Sorry should have been clearer

Comment: Hi, it is still not entirely clear what you mean, but if you want to automate running all the cells in a notebook similar to "restart and run all"; you can write a separate .py script using ExecutePreprocessor from the nbconvert library.

Comment: This is what I wanted to know, but I didn't know the term for it! thank you, will check it out

Comment: No problem, make sure to check this one out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67811531/how-can-i-execute-a-ipynb-notebook-file-in-a-python-script