# How to run a jupyter lab notebook as a .bat script (using Anaconda Environment)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Hi I have a Jupyerlab notebook called:

`SQL Queries.ipynb` which runs off the environment `QueryEnv` in `Anaconda`.

The file lives in the directory `C:\Users\Latitude User\OneDrive\Projects\`

Is there a way in which to run a notebook file as a `.bat` or do i have to convert the notebook to a `.py` file?

Previously i have used the following `.bat` scripts for a `.py` file in the `ModelEnv` of `Anaconda`:

```
@ECHO OFF 
TITLE Execute python script on anaconda environment
ECHO Please Wait...
:: Section 1: Activate the environment.
ECHO ============================
ECHO Conda Activate
ECHO ============================
@CALL "C:\Users\Latitude User\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" ModelEnv
:: Section 2: Execute python script.
ECHO ============================
ECHO Model.py
ECHO ============================
python "C:\Users\Latitude User\OneDrive\Projects\Model.py"
ECHO ============================
ECHO End
ECHO ============================

PAUSE
```

Can I do this for a notebook file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run an .ipynb Jupyter Notebook from terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545402/how-to-run-an-ipynb-jupyter-notebook-from-terminal)

Comment: The question is more MAC based but I was hoping to get some help with the Anaconda element as well. Whether I can activate the Anaconda environment and then run the notebook like I have done with .py as above