# Running Jupyter notebook (and generating plots) from the command line

Tags: julia

I'm trying to use the terminal to run a jupyter notebook (kernel: Julia v1.6.2), which contains generated using Plots.jl, before uploading the notebook to github for viewing on nbviewer.com.

Following this question:

[How to run an .ipynb Jupyter Notebook from terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545402/how-to-run-an-ipynb-jupyter-notebook-from-terminal)

I have been using nbconvert as follows:

jupyter nbconvert --execute --to notebook --inplace

This runs the notebook (if you tweak the timeout limits), however, it does not display plots when using Plots.jl, even when I explicitly call display(plot()) at the end of a cell.

Does anyone have any idea how notebooks can be run remotely in such a manner that plots will be generated and displayed, particularly when using Julia?

Comment: Just to be clear, the last line of the cell is `display(plot(x, y; options...))` (or however your plot call looks), not just an empty `display(plot())`, right?

Comment: Sorry, yes that's correct.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to generate `Plots.jl` plots by getting from `IJulia` the same configuration it uses to run notebooks (this is probably the most sure way when you have many Pyhtons etc.).

```
using Conda, IJulia
Conda.add("nbconvert") # I made sure nbconvert is installed

mycmd = IJulia.find_jupyter_subcommand("nbconvert")
append!(mycmd.exec, ["--ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=600","--to", "notebook" ,"--execute", "note1.ipynb"])
```

Now `mycmd` has exactly the same environment as seen by IJulia so we can do `run(mycmd)`:

```
julia> run(mycmd)
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook note1.ipynb to notebook
Starting kernel event loops.
[NbConvertApp] Writing 23722 bytes to note1.nbconvert.ipynb
```

The outcome got saved to `note1.nbconvert.ipynb`, I open it with nteract to show that graphs actually got generated:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This almost works - I'm just getting the following error in the notebook, in place of a plot: No (safe) renderer could be found for output. It has the following MIME types: image/svg+xml.

Answer (score 0):

Launch notebook with `using IJulia` and `notebook()` in the REPL