# Can I execute a file (or some lines of python) within a running jupyterlab kernel for a notebook?

Tags: command-line, jupyter-lab

I've got a notebook that has got a bit unwieldy and I'm doing some refactoring which isn't fun.

I was wondering if it would be possible to execute code in this notebook from the command line for debugging.

Ideally, I would run something like:

```
run-in-jupyter $notebook file.py
```

and see the output from the command line. There is an interpreter in jupyterlab that can do this, so this make me think that it is possible.

I have a brief search but couldn't find much

- [How to run an .ipynb Jupyter Notebook from terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545402/how-to-run-an-ipynb-jupyter-notebook-from-terminal) I explicitly don't want to do this (I want to run commands in an existing instace)
- There is [this library](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/stable/messaging.html) but this seems quite involved and some of the results I found on the internet where people not being able to use the library

Answer (score 1):

[jupyter console](https://jupyter-console.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`pip install jupyter-console`) connects to a running jupyter kernel from the kernel. Details on running kernels can be found amongst jupyter's run time files, on my box these live in `~/.local/share/jupyter/runtime`. You can find the path to the kernel data file corresponding to an open workbook with `%config IPKernelApp.connection_file` which will look something like `~/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-55da8a07-b67d-4584-9ec6-f24e4a26cbbd.json`.

You can then connect from the command line with

`jupyter console --existing ~/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-55da8a07-b67d-4584-9ec6-f24e4a26cbbd.json`

You can pipe commands into it as shown

```
echo h=87 | jupyter console --existing 55da8a07-b67d-4584-9ec6-f24e4a26cbbd 'h=57' --simple-prompt -y
```