# Run Jupyter Notebook (.ipynb) from command line as if it were a .py file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert

I am authoring a Jupyter notebook on my local machine that will eventually be run on a remote server (which is running Ubuntu).  Every time I need to make a change I must export the notebook as a `.py` file and then call it from the command line of the server.

I'd like to be able to run this on the fly, calling one command that takes the current `.ipynb` file and executes it on the command line as if it were a `.py`, showing all the print statements and output you'd expect if the `.py` were run.  I thought `nbconverter` might do the trick using something like the following command:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to script --execute nbconvert_test.ipynb
```

As it turnout, this does not convert the `.ipynb` to a `.py` file to be executed on the command line as I would like, but rather it creates a new file called `nbconvert_test.py` in the same directory which I would then have to run in a separate command.  I'd really like to prevent the creation of that file every time I make even a small change, and to skip the extra step on the command line.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running .ipynb from terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545402/running-ipynb-from-terminal)

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, that question is similar, but the answers provided to that question did not seem to interpret the request as looking for a solution in one line.

Comment: http://deeplearning.lipingyang.org/2018/03/28/run-jupyter-notebook-script-from-terminal/

Answer (score 7):

You can send the jupyter nbconvert to stranded output and pipe that to python.

```
jupyter nbconvert --to script --execute --stdout test_nbconvert.ipynb | python
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  It returns a Syntax Error for invalid syntax

Comment: try piping to ipython instead of python? You might be using some ipython specific syntax in the notebook.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is a small shell script that has three parts

1. converting the notebook
2. executing created script
3. removing the script

create a file `runnb.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
# First argument is the notebook you would like to run
notebook=$1
scriptname="$(basename $notebook .ipynb)".py

jupyter nbconvert --to script --execute ${notebook} && python ${scriptname}
rm ${scriptname}
```

use as such:

```
$ ./runnb.sh nbconvert_test.ipynb
```

EDIT:
[According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545402/running-ipynb-from-terminal?rq=1), this command should do just fine `jupyter nbconvert --execute test_nbconvert.ipynb` (just leav out the `--to` flag

Comment: Thanks Robin-I think without the --to flag it creates an html file in the same directory that includes the output, but doesn't fit the bill exactly.  Your script in three lines may do the trick.  I'll pay with that now...Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work, it says xyz.py not found for rm command

Answer (score 0):

With the `boar` package, you can run your notebook within a python code, using:

```py
from boar.running import run_notebook

outputs = run_notebook("nbconvert_test.ipynb")
```

---

For more information, see:

https://github.com/alexandreCameron/boar/blob/master/USAGE.md

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error
xyz.py not found for rm command
Then I ran the script inside the conda virtual environment and it worked.

```
conda activate
```

Comment: You may want to direct this at Raymond's comment from 2016. As an aside, there's other modern ways to do this now in addition to `jupyter nbconvert`. One of my favorites is using [jupytext on the command line to execute a notebook](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-cli.html). There's also papermill, ploomber, and nbtoolbelt. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-run-a-notebook-using-command-line/3475?u=fomightez) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/run-ipynb-on-a-remote-workstation-so-that-all-results-will-be-save-in-the-same-pynb/13340/2?u=fomightez).